# Avoid two versions of function for `const X&` and `X&`

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this code:

```
template<typename X>
struct Store { X x; };

template<typename X>
Store<X> store(X x) { /* a lot of code */ return Store<X>{x}; }

void foo_cr(const int& a) {
    auto s = store(a);
}

void foo_r(int& a) {
    auto s = store(a);
}
```

Is there a way to modify the function `store` such that it returns `Store<const int&>` in `foo_cr` and `Store<int&>` in `foo_r` without providing two versions of `store` for `const X&` and `X&`?

---

Right now my code looks like this:

```
template<typename X>
Store<const X&> store(const X& x) { /* a lot of code */ return Store<const X&>{x}; }

template<typename X>
Store<X&> store(X& x) { /* a lot of code */ return Store<X&>{x}; }
```

The function body is exactly the same and I would like to avoid the duplicated definition.

Comment: Is there a reason why the store parameter can't always be `const`?

Comment: @KillianDS: Sometimes I want to change the stored object...

Comment: @Danvil, why the `&` next to the template parameter in the update?

Comment: I've just rolled back your edit. I'm sorry but you can't just update the whole code question after someone answered. You just invalidated two answers that someone spent time writing. If you have doubts on one of the answers, please add a comment. Otherwise, if you have a different question, post another question. Thanks.

Comment: @Jefffrey: My update was a more explicit demonstration of the intend of my question. I think it is valuable information. Please excuse if my wording was misleading or offended you.

Comment: @Danvil I disagree. Your update changed the code referred to in the other answers completely. With your update my answer and probably Daniel's one would need to change radically. And no, I'm not offended at all.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to go in a rollback war. So I'll just delete my answer, downvote this question and vote to close for "unclear what you are asking". Have a nice day sir.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Why so unfriendly? I really hope your mood improves before you run into an unaware coworker today...

Comment: @Danvil, I'm trying to be as professional and as calm as possible. The downvote is necessary because this question is unclear (which is one of the reasons that pops up if you hover the mouse over any downvote arrows). The close vote serves the same purpose and helps SO being a better place. I'm not taking this personally in any way. I'm just exercising my "right" to vote questions that I don't see fit for SO. If other 4 members will agree with me, this question will get closed. After that someone can cast a vote to reopen if they see it fit.

Comment: If, by then, you still don't agree with the community you'll be able to complain on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and/or flag for moderation attention. I wish you good luck.

Comment: @Jefffrey: You say it is unclear, but don't want me to clarify and give more information. That is confusing.

Comment: @Danvil, you are free to give more informations any time you want. My problem was that your first update defined two completely different pieces of code and it was unclear to me to which to refer to. Now, I'm sorry, but I need to move on.

Answer (score 2):

The following might be what you are looking for:

```
template<typename X>
Store<X&> store(X& xa)
{
    auto x=xa;
    /* a lot of code */
    return Store<X&>{x};
}
```

It'll deduce `X` to either `Y` or `const Y`, but it'll limit you to references. Also, the `auto x=xa;` will make sure you get a copy of type `Y` inside of your method. Not sure if this really fits your needs, but without further information it's hard to tell.

Comment: Even your edit (which was rolled back by Jefffrey which I personally find a bit harsh) doesn't help: It depends on the `/* a lot of code */` part and what you do with `x`. I think both my answer as well as Jefffrey's answer offer some ideas, but you'll have to check yourself what fits your needs best. As this is often the case: SO can offer ideas and help you to learn, but applying it is still up to you :)